# ERRORS: book.Book.author: (fields.E300) book.Book.author: (fields.E307)

Tags: python, django, web

My English is poor, sorry

This is my struct:

```
bookstore
---author(app1)
---book(app2)
```

Or in code:

```
from django.db import models
from author.models import Profile

from django.contrib import admin

class Book(models.Model):

      title        = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
      page         = models.IntegerField()
      price        = models.IntegerField()
      author = models.ForeignKey(
      'Profile',
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
  publish_date = models.DateField()

  class Meta(object):
    db_table = "book"

class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass

admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

mysql have some data, now I want to use them to show my web, not to do that creat data in database. Thank you guys!

I have a question:

My Django == 1.9 , python == 3 , windows10

I want to use mysql (my database contect is really do it).
When I find some resource, I will see that
`python manage.py sql [appname]` it is Django to SQL
when I want to use Django to mysql.
Can I use `python manage.py inspectdb`? It will have a models.py
`python manage.py sql [appname]` = `python manage.py inspectdb`?

ERRORS:

```
book.Book.author: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Profile', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
book.Book.author: (fields.E307) The field book.Book.author was declared with a lazy reference to 'book.profile', but app 'book' doesn't provide model 'profile'.
```

Comment: You should refer to this as `'app1.Profile'`, so not `'Profile'`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Book` model, you refer with a field named `author` to a model `Profile`. Since that model is defined in *another* app, you should refer to it as `app_name.ModelName`, so likely that is:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    page = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'app1.Profile',  # add name of the app
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    publish_date = models.DateField()
```

If you named this model `Author` however, as the question *text* (not the code), seems to suggest, you should use `app1.Author`. Of course you replace `app1` with the real name of the app.

This is described in the documentation in the [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> To refer to **models defined in another application**, you can
>   **explicitly specify a model with the full application label**. For example, if the Manufacturer model above is defined in another
>   application called production, you’d need to use:
>
> ```
> class Car(models.Model):
>     manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(
>         'production.Manufacturer',
>         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
>     )
> ```